# Tabulator show value instead title in autocomplete when I start to edit cell

Tags: tabulator

I create a table.

There is a column which has `editor:"autocomplete"`, `listItemFormatter`, `searchFunc`, `formatter:"lookup"`

Here is its setting:

```
let column =  {title: "Показателя", field:"parameter", editor:"autocomplete",
  editorParams: {
    values: values,
    listItemFormatter: (value, title) => {
      if (this.displayGroupTitle && value !== undefined) {
        return title + " - (" + this.parameters.find(parameter => String(parameter.id) === value).groupTitle + ")"
      } else {
        return title
      }
    },
    allowEmpty: true,
    searchFunc: (term, values) => {
      let matches = []
      let foundParameters = findParameterByTerm(term, this.parameters)
      values.forEach(function(item){
        if(foundParameters.indexOf(item.value) !== -1){
          matches.push(item);
        }
      });
      return matches;
    },
    // showListOnEmpty: true
  },
  formatter:"lookup",
  formatterParams: values
}
```

When I start to edit cells with value, cells show value instead of the title of value.

There's an inactive cell here:

[image]

But it's the same cell when I edit it:

[image]

How to do to show title when I edit cell with value?

**UPDATE:**

Values variable has:

```
{
  "40":"Выручка",
  "41":"Чистая прибыль",
  "42":"Прибыль до налогооблажения",
  "43":"Выловая прибыль",
  "44":"Себестоимость продаж",
  "45":"Финансовые доходы",
  "46":"Финансовые расходы"
}
```

Comment: without knowing how your values variable is configured it is impossible to provide you with a response as to why this is happening

Comment: Oli, I add configuration of values variable.